# How to read a string until new line except for the first char is newline itself in C?

Tags: c, string, scanf, format-specifiers

```
void Init() {
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Input the cup name:");

    scanf("%[^\n]s", array_of_water[indexx].name); 
    array_of_water[indexx].water = rand() % 31 + 20;
}
```

`"%[^\n]s"`
I know it will read the string until it encounters newline. But, How to make exception for the first char to be not newline.

If I press enter on my keyboard the string will save `\n` as its element. But I don't want that, I want to let user enter except for newline itself. Besides that, how the format specifiers change if I want read until encounter alphabet/number/other symbols?

Comment: First of all passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as leading to *undefined behavior*. One compiler and standard library have added it as a non-portable and very non-standard extension. Don't use it. It's not even needed first thing in your program, as the input buffer will be empty anyway.

Comment: Secondly, I really recommend you kind of forget that `scanf` exists for input.  To read a full line use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: `"%[^\n]"` without a _width_ is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: "If I press enter on my keyboard the string will save "\n" as its element." --> No.  that did not happen.  Also please report the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Andrew530, Who or what text suggested an `s` in `"%[^\n]s"`?

Comment: @Some programmer dude  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74743770/how-to-read-a-string-until-new-line-except-for-the-first-char-is-newline-itself#comment131915572_74743770) missing `fflush()`.  As is the comment is unclear.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh yeah, seems I left out quite an important bit. Yes the comment is about `fflush` and passing `stdin` to it.

Answer (score 2):

> How to read a string until new line except for the first char is newline itself ...?

**Correct use of `scanf()` will succeed**

OP's `scanf("%[^\n]s", array_of_water[indexx].name);` lacks context as the size of `array_of_water[indexx].name` is unknown, as well as the input.  `fflush(stdin);` is also undefined behavior.  Delete it.

**The `s` in `"%[^\n]s"` is amiss.**

Drop the `s`.

```
char buf[100];
int count = scanf("%99[^\n]", buf);
switch (count) {
  case EOF: puts("End of file or input error"); break;
  case   1: printf("Success <%s>\n", buf); break;
  case   0: puts("Nothing read"); break;
}
```

Left to do:

- Consume rest of non-`'\n'` line if length of `buf` was 99.
- Consume final `'\n'`.
- Handle pesky *null characters*, if they were read.

---

Easier to just use `fgets()`.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; // Lop off potential \n
  printf("Success <%s>\n", buf);
} else {
  case EOF: puts("End of file or input error"); break;
}
```

Left to do:

- Maybe consume rest of non-`'\n'` line if length of `buf` read was 99.

Comment: Note that used with the same buffer length, `scanf("%99[^\n]", buf)` and `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)` behave the same only if 99 or more bytes have been read from `stdin` without any newline. If fewer bytes are available, the newline if consumed and stored into the target array by `fgets()` but left in the input stream by `scanf()`.

Comment: @Also: `scanf()` fails, does not modify the target array and returns `0` if a newline is read from `stdin` immediately whereas `fgets()` happily reads an empty line consisting of a single `\n` byte.